# in which language does https checks automatically the certification

Tags: https, certificate, ssl-certificate

I need to understand in which languages, when creating a new Https connections there is/or not an automatic check that the certification is valid.

a search online did not give me anything good,
can you help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is incorrect. It is not up to any particular language, it is up to underlying HTTPS module that creates HTTPS connection. In the case of Windows, it is up to SChannel module which performs automatic certificate validation. In other operating systems/applications, their own modules are used.

Regardless of operating system/application, HTTPS module exposes APIs for client applications which can be used by a variety of programming languages. All major HTTPS modules (including SChannel) do perform SSL certificate validation.